# time data 2019-03-31T01:55:00CET doesn't match format specified pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

almost new to pandas. Simply enough: csv data with 2 columns, one of it is datetime:

```
DATE,VALUE
2019-06-01 00:00:00,0.0
.....
```

when using `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`, pandas is reading the datetime columns as:

```
2019-01-01T02:25:00CET
```

so when trying to read the column with `d.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` I'm getting the following error:

`time data 2019-03-31T01:55:00CET doesn't match format specified`

any suggestions? I tried to use the `utc = True` parameter but it is not solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just read about strptime https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

```
import datetime

timestring = "2019-01-01T02:25:00CET" 

# Create datetime objects
d0 = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestring, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SCET")
print(d0)
2019-01-01 02:25:00
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about timezone information, you can simply do:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'].str[:18], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

Just remember the "T" between date and time.

Comment: If I do care about tz? In the file I have mixed CET and CEST values.

Comment: Do you want to convert to utc time?